# Proof that a set is dense in the square integrable function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $p(x)$ be a polynomial in $R^n$. Consider the set $A$ of function of the  type  $$\psi(x)=p(x)e^{-\alpha x^2}$$
where $\alpha >0$

How too proof that the set  A is dense in $L^2(R^n)$ where  $L^2(R^n)$ means square integrable function?

My idea of proof is this . Let's take $\alpha_0$ such we have  $e^{-\alpha x^2} \leq e^{-\alpha_0 x^2}$ then we would have $\psi(x)\leq p(x)e^{-\alpha_0 x^2}=\psi_0(x).$So we would have

$ \left\lVert f-\psi\right\rVert \leq \left\lVert f-\psi_0\right\rVert = e^{\alpha_0 x^2}\left\lVert f-p(x)\right\rVert < e^{-\alpha_0 x^2}\epsilon$
where i used that polynomials are dense. Finally we  would have

$ \left\lVert f-\psi\right\rVert<\epsilon$

is this proof correct?

Comment: Polynomials don't belong to $L^{2}$ so your argument doesn't work.

Comment: you are right. Can you give me a proof

Comment: Non trivial polynomials are greater than a constant outside some big enough radius, and the volume of the complement of a ball is infinity. However if you can use the fact that $C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is dense in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$, this will translate this to a simpler problem.

Comment: What exactly is your set $A$? Do you vary $p$ or $\alpha$, or both?

Comment: both $p$ and $\alpha$  vary

Comment: When you write $x^2$, do you mean the inner product of $x$ with itself, i.e $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i^2 $?

Comment: yes that what it means